# UICollectionViewFlowLayout position

Tags: ios, ios7, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a problem

When I click the tabcontoller `uıcollectionviewflowlayout` position is changing :(

The following code does not work

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];


    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *collectionViewLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)self.myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout;

    collectionViewLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

before  image:

[image: http://i.hizliresim.com/O3zA8P.png]

When I click the tabcontoller
after image:

[image: http://i.hizliresim.com/12ZvBb.png]

please help me

other image upload

[image: http://i.hizliresim.com/LYRnZG.png]

Comment: Which one is wrong ? first or second ?

Comment: wrong is second .  first image is true

Comment: did you try to put self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO; in viewdidload ?

Comment: yes I have tried but not . I solved the problem .   self.myCollectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets =UIEdgeInsetsZero;  in viewWillLayoutSubviews

Answer (score 0):

**updated:**
Remove

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *collectionViewLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)self.myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout;
collectionViewLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

from `viewWillAppear` and put it back in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I am put collectionview inside uiview. When I click the tabcontoller,  cell in the collectionview sectionInset is changed :(  Or cell position approximately 20 px changing.

Comment: have you checked my updated answer and executed it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
        - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [self.myCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:PhotoCellIdentifier bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
                forCellWithReuseIdentifier:PhotoCellIdentifier];        
        self.myCollectionView.delegate=self;
        self.myCollectionView.dataSource=self;  
 [self.myCollectionView  setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];      
         [self yukle];
    }

        -(void) storkontrol:(NSArray*)skulist{

        [[RMStore defaultStore] requestProducts:[NSSet setWithArray:skulist] success:^(NSArray *products, NSArray *invalidProductIdentifiers) {

            if (products.count ==0)
            {
                self.eserList = nil;

                [self sitedeveriyokbilgi];




            } else

            {

                NSMutableArray *ll = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                int i =0;

                // satın alışverişte alınan ürünelr geliyor

               // NSLog(@"RMStore dan ürünler bekleniyor..");

                for (SKProduct*urun in products) {

                    //  NSLog(@"ürün : %@",urun.productIdentifier);

                    for (EserFiles*eser in self.eserList) {

                        if ([urun.productIdentifier isEqualToString:eser.eser.eserstokkod])
                        {
                            eser.eser.product = urun;
                            [ll insertObject:eser atIndex:i];
                            i++;


                        }
                    }

                }


                //            NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"eser.esersayi" ascending:NO selector:@selector(compare:)];
                //            [ll sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];

                self.eserList = ll;



                //  [HesapViewController setEserListVitrin: ll];

               // [AyarlarViewController setEserListVitrin: ll];

                [global setEserListVitrin: ll];



              //  NSLog(@"RMStore dan ürün çekme  işlemi bitti");



                [self.myCollectionView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

                _productsRequestFinished = YES;




                [spinnerorta stopAnimating];


            }




        } failure:^(NSError *error) {
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

            [spinnerorta stopAnimating];

            NSLog(@"failure:^(NSError *error urunlist %@",error.localizedDescription);
        }];


    }

        -(void)sitedeveriyokbilgi{

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, self.view.frame.size.width, 270)];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        label.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        label.numberOfLines = 0;

        label.text = @"Listelenecek eser bulunamadı";


        [self.view addSubview:label];

        NSLog(@"Listelenecek eser bulunamadı");

         [spinnerorta stopAnimating];


    }

        -(void)yukle{



        spinnerorta = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                       initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        spinnerorta.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        spinnerorta.center = self.view.center;

        [spinnerorta startAnimating];

        [self.view addSubview: spinnerorta];


        //eğer kategoriden geliyorsa hiç bir zamanön bellekleme olmayacak

       __block NSArray *arry  ;
         NSMutableArray *skulist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

        //ana sayfa ise
        if (self.gelenviewid==1)
        {

            if ([[global getEserList] count] ==0 )
            {

               // NSLog(@"yeni liste alınıyor.......");
                NSMutableArray *skulist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                JSONLoader *jsonLoader = [[JSONLoader alloc] init];

                 arry = [jsonLoader locationsFromJSONFile];


            } else{


                self.eserList =[global getEserList];




              //  NSLog(@"ön bellekten doldu....");


               [self.myCollectionView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];



               // [spinnerorta stopAnimating];

                return ;

            }




        } else if(self.gelenviewid==2)
        {


            arry  = [JSONLoader getEserlerToKategory:self.catId];



        }



            if ([arry count] >0)
            {

                self.eserList =  arry;



                for (EserFiles*eserfile in self.eserList) {


                    // NSLog(@"sayı  :%d  %@",eserfile.eser.esersayi,eserfile.eser.kisaisim);

                    [skulist addObject:eserfile.eser.eserstokkod];
                }

                //  dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                //                 ^{


                [self storkontrol:skulist];




                //   });

            } else {



            dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{


                [spinnerorta stopAnimating];
                [self sitedeveriyokbilgi];

            });



            }



        });



    }

        -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        int count  = self.eserList.count;

        return count;
    }

        - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                      cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


        // [collectionView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];



        EserFiles *esefiles  =[self.eserList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        Eser *eser = esefiles.eser;


        UrunCell *urunCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"UrunCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];



        UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                                            initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        spinner.frame = CGRectMake((urunCell.frame.size.width-25)/2, 50, 24, 24);
        [spinner startAnimating];


        [urunCell.contentView addSubview: spinner];




        NSString *title = @"";

        if ([eser.kisaisim isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || [eser.kisaisim isEqualToString:@""]){

            title = eser.isim;
        } else title = eser.kisaisim;



        urunCell.UrunIsim.text=title;


        //   NSLog(@"title  :  %@",title);



        [urunCell.UrunImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:eser.kapakYol]
                          placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"] options:indexPath.row == 0 ? SDWebImageRefreshCached : 0];



        [spinner stopAnimating];


        return urunCell;

    }

        -(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

        self.vitrinDetayViewController =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VitrinDetayViewController"];

        EserFiles *esefiles  =[self.eserList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        self.vitrinDetayViewController.eser = esefiles;



        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.vitrinDetayViewController animated:YES];

    }

        - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

        // [self.myCollectionView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];


        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *collectionViewLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)self.myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout;
      //  collectionViewLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);

        //[self.myCollectionView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];

       // self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
        [spinnerorta stopAnimating];

    }
```

Comment: See now I have updated your code. Check if this works. Accept my answer if it works.